# Brunch and npm scoped packages (such as @cycle/core)

Tags: npm, brunch

I really prefer Brunch over Webpack (for all of the obvious reasons), but am trying to work with Cycle.js - in particular the @cycle/core and @cycle/dom packages. These are installed using the 'npm install @cycle/core @cycle/dom --save-dev' command.

However even before I try to import that code, brunch fails to build because of the use of the npm scoped package syntax.

Can anybody suggest a fix or workaround for this?

Thanks Martin

Comment: Try using brunch from github: `npm install -g brunch/brunch`